# Rails 5 - Associated Models, with the child being used by multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Having an issue with the proper order of associations.

I have a `Character` a `CharClass` and all `CharClass`es have a set of available `Perks` to them. a `Character` can choose which `Perks` to take and which to ignore.

I will manually populate the `CharClass` table and `Perks` table with the set-in-stone choices.

Thanks to Benjamin's comment below I have modified my schema to look as this(Minus non-related stuff):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180408124936) do

  create_table "char_classes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "class_name"
    t.string "class_perks"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "character_perks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "character_id"
    t.integer "class_perk_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["character_id"], name: "index_character_perks_on_character_id"
    t.index ["class_perk_id"], name: "index_character_perks_on_class_perk_id"
  end

  create_table "characters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "character_name"
    t.integer "character_level"
    t.integer "character_experience"
    t.integer "character_gold"
    t.integer "campaign_id"
    t.integer "char_class_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["campaign_id"], name: "index_characters_on_campaign_id"
    t.index ["char_class_id"], name: "index_characters_on_char_class_id"
  end


  create_table "class_perks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "perk_description"
    t.integer "currently_has"
    t.integer "maximum_available"
    t.integer "perk_id"
    t.integer "char_class_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["char_class_id"], name: "index_class_perks_on_char_class_id"
    t.index ["perk_id"], name: "index_class_perks_on_perk_id"
  end


  create_table "perks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "perk_text"
    t.integer "perk_max_count"
    t.integer "perk_current_count", default: 0
    t.integer "char_class_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["char_class_id"], name: "index_perks_on_char_class_id"
  end

end
```

This has resolved all data errors, but has a bit of redundancy. Due to the SO Flow of One Answer per Question, this did handle my primary ask for the original need. I will make an additional question for the follow-up.

Comment: 0
down vote
I saw your Reddit post. Thanks for linking to StackoverFlow. I want to help, but dude. I think we need less backstory of the app and more of the current code to look at.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for the tip! Trying to get better at writing the questions; I assumed the back story would help understand the need but re-reading it I can see what you mean. I will edit it with additional info shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts on how you might want to set up your tables, but I don't think there's an obvious best answer here. It's pretty much  what you were going after but there are semantics I'll cover.

```
CharClass
has_many :class_perks
has_many :characters

ClassPerk
belongs_to :char_class      # Use intermediate table if you want has_many/has_many
has_many :character_perks   # between CharClass and ClassPerk for perk overlap

Character
belongs_to :char_class
has_many :class_perks, :through => char_class
has_many :character_perks

CharacterPerk
belongs_to :character
belongs_to :class_perk
```

This set up allows you to check which perks are available to a character based on class, and still keep the character's progress separate from the class perks.

Some nitpicky things:

- belongs_to means that this table/model is the one that contains the foreign id to the relevant model. I think it makes more sense for the character to have the reference to the class.
- A couple of the errors you're running into don't seem directly related to the question, but could be side effects of weirdly set up tables. I don't mind going through them here but some people might argue they should be separate posts. It might be more beneficial to show more of your schema rather than the migration.
- Regarding the save error, if you're using strong params, remember to permit char_class_id and that the input name matches the attribute on the table

Comment: I will modify my schema to look similar tomorrow and post an update! Most of my errors I actually over-came, but wanted to provide evidence that I did go 'through the notions' before posting, and to give an idea on my thought process. After reading more about associations, I definitely think I have it inverted. I will try out the idea of an intermediate table for perks.